# Convert Varchar Apr-14-2015 to 04/14/2015 IN SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a field that contains a value as Apr-14-2015 and I need to convert it to a Datetime field as 04/14/2015

Comment: The better question is *why* are you storing date time values in a `varchar` in the first place? Also, there's no such thing as a "field" in SQL Server.

Comment: I don't have control over them storing date time value in varchar.  Sorry about my terminology usage, just trying to get an answer.

Comment: *"I don't have control over them storing date time value in varchar."* Then feedback to whomever can to fix their design. [`varchar` is NOT a one size fits all data type](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-varchar-is-not-a-one-size-fits-all-data-type/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the hyphens to spaces and use format 100:

```
select convert(date, replace(field, '-', ' '), 100)
```

You can use `try_convert()` instead if some of the values are not in the right format.

Comment: I tried your code but then I received this message - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: The perils of storing `varchar` data when you have 5 other datatypes that are far better suited @DavidCarreonSr. .

Comment: I was doing something wrong, but your solution worked.  Thank You